# Rollup plugin alias not working, when used to alias mock function. Simple never finishes

Tags: rollup

My objective is to mock out a function, using Rollup plugin alias, in a typescript-sapper project.

My roll-up plugins array looks like this:

```js
plugins: [
    replace({
        'process.browser': false,
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(mode),
    }),
    json(),
    svelte({
        generate: 'ssr',
        hydratable: true,
        preprocess, // : sveltePreprocess(),
        dev,
    }),
    resolve({
        dedupe: ['svelte'],
    }),
    alias({
        entries: [
            {
                find: /get-user-from-client-jwt/,
                replacement: '__mocks__/get-user-from-client-jwt',
            },
        ],
    }),
    commonjs(),
    typescript({ sourceMap: true, tsconfig: 'tsconfig.rollup.json' }),
],
```

However when I run this, it never finishes - keeps building for-ever. If I remove `alias` from the plugins, everything works.

Why is it timing out?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `alias` needs to go before the `resolve` plugin (and potentially others).